# Load image Dynamically via Java servlet

Tags: java, image, servlets, tomcat8

I am trying to load images from server to my JSP

My files are:

**image.jsp**

```
<img src='servlet1' height='300px'/>
```

**DisplayImage.java**

```
public class DisplayImage extends HttpServlet {
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
       response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
       ServletOutputStream out;
       out = response.getOutputStream();    
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("path/to/my/img.jpg"); 
       BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
       BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
       int ch =0;
       while((ch=bin.read())!=-1){
            bout.write(ch);
       }    
       bin.close();
       fin.close();
       bout.close();
       out.close();
    }
}
```

Application I'm supposed to build is a Vehicle Directory where I can upload images, and these images are stored in a folder `/home/upload/` outside `CATALINA`
(**NB:** I didn't use a folder inside project directory coz I am deploying the project via ***.war** file, which removes every files inside when a new version needs to be deployed.)

I want to display the details and image based on search parameters.

( **Edit:** I have the file name stored in database when I upload them, so  can get the list of image names from DB for a particular vehicle, Since it is stored in folder `/home/upload/` , full path will be like `/home/upload/fileName.jpg` which I need to pass to servlet to load)

Problem I face is that:

image src attribute is specified as `servlet1` and the servlet by default serves the image from path defined in **DisplayImage.java** file

Is there any way that I can pass `/another/file/Path.jpg` or `fileName.jpg` to the servlet so that I can display other image files too,

Comment: Please be more clear what you want to achieve. How do you want to pass the image path to your servlet? Usually you have a folder with images and let the default servlet deliver the images. Or your servlet can evaluate the URL path or the GET parameters to determine the image name. You should first define the expected behaviour and then think about the implementation.

Comment: This one helped, didn't knew passing argument to the Servlet , changed `src` from `servlet1?imagePath=/home/upload/one.jpg` Thanks a lot <3

Comment: You should be careful with such an absolut path. This might be a security hole. Someone could read every file on your system by using your servlet.

Comment: No, I'm just passing the file name in src attribute, as:
 `<img src="servlet?img='myImage.jpg' alt='Image not loaded' />` 
 and path is evaluated inside servlet. 
thanks for mentioning the vulnerability :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, In JSP, you can pass your search parameters in request.
Like

```
<input id="imageSerach" name="imageSerach"/>
<div id="ImageContent"/>
```

and make ajax call to servlet with imageSearch param.

```
$.ajax({
  url: servleturl,
  data: {
    imageSerach : $('#imageSerach').val()
  },
  success: function(responseData){
    $('#ImageContent').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + responseData + '" />');
  }
});
```

Servlet :-

public class DisplayImage extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

```
   String fileName = req.getParameter("imageSerach");

   response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
   ServletOutputStream out;
    File f = new File("path/of/file/"+fileName);
    if (f.exists())
       out = response.getOutputStream();    
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("path/of/file/"+fileName); 
       BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
       BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
       int ch =0;
       while((ch=bin.read())!=-1){
            bout.write(ch);
       }    
       bin.close();
       fin.close();
       bout.close();
       out.close();
    else
       // no file exit
   
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, I was just trying to call a servlet from src attribute in `<img/>` and just needed to pass a filename to the servlet so that It can help the servlet to identify which file to be served. Your solution works in case of directly searching the file name as input, but my stupid question was to pass an value to servlet which is plain and simple `GET` method as `<img src="servlet?img='myImage.jpg' alt='Image not loaded' />` , Thanks for the time anyways